# knife ssh/winrm -a and -m can not work together?

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

I'm using the latest knife-winrm(0.5.13) and chef(11.4.4). It looks like no matter what I specify the address attribute to use for the connection, it will always use the FQDN.

I used "-a ipaddress", but the error message shows it still use the FQDN. BTW, "ipaddress" is valid one I have checked with "knife node show -l"

Comment: Hello! I'm glad that you were able to find a solution to your problem. Could you please answer your own question and then mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I found this problem only happens when you use -m(manual-list) to list nodes. Without -m, -a will work fine.

**UPDATE**: Realise that the server name with '-m' is the address used for connect, just replace the node name with IP address when using '-m' to solve this issue.